# Proper way of updating data in nested components react/ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say we have a list of Projects, and each project contains a bunch of Workorders. Both Projects and Workorders share a property, "Status".

If you change the status of project from "In progress" to "Started", then this change will propagate to all Workorders inside of that project. Likewise, if we change the status of one Workorder, it will change the status of that project.

We have a Project view that contains a list of Projects where we can see the status, and we can also go into to the detailed view and see the Workorders for that specific project. From here we can change the status for the project, and we can also go to the detailed view for each Workorder. In the detailed view, we can also change the status for each Workorder.

The problem is I can't find a good way of doing this. My first attempt was to update the local list which are fetched and filtered in the backend. So let's say a user changes the status from "In progress" to "Started" and a filter is applied to filter for "Started". We don't want it to show anymore. So all data must be fetched and filtered from backend after actually adding something.

What is the proper way of updating each view? Currently I pass a function to each component which recursively tells each view it's time to fetch whatever data it needs from backend.

This way is not good at all as we need to pass refreshData to so many components... And hard to keep track of. You can go even more deeply  than Workorder to "tasks" etc.

What could be a good solution to this problem?

```
interface Project {
   bunch of props for project
   workorders: Workorder[] 
}

interface Workorder {
  bunch of props for workorder
  tasks: Task[]
}

interface Task {
  ...
} 

interface Props {
  id: number,
  refreshData: () => void
}

const WorkOrderDetailedView ({id, refreshData} : Props) => {
   // Shows the specific workorder
   // Update status etc.
}


const DetailedProjectsView ({id, refreshData}: Props ) => {
   // Show the more detailed view of the project as a modal
   // We can also change status / other information about the specific project here
   // In this view we can also go to workorder detailed view   

    const getProjectById = () =>  get project from backend
    <WorkOrder .... refreshData={getProjectById}/>
}


const Projects () => {
      const [showDetailedView, setShowDetailedView] = useState(false)
      const [id, setId] = useState<0>

      const getAllProjects = () => call from backend
      
     <List of Projects>
     <Button onClick={() => {
               setShowDetailedView(true); 
               setId(currentIdOfItemYouClicked
                } />
     <DetailedProjectsView show={showDetailedView} id={id} refrehsData={getAllProjects} /> 
     
}
```

Comment: Why are you filtering on the backend? If you fetch all the data initially you can just filter the data you already have.

Comment: Well, if it were me and my stuff, I'd have react query pulling data so I'd just set it as a mutation and let it handle knowing to refresh.

Comment: @Nikki9696 Could you be kind to explain a bit further?

Comment: If you use react query, it has a context provider. You can basically tell it that something you did invalidates queries and their components will refetch. https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query